# How do i open a chm file with java in mac os?

Tags: java, macos, file, io, chm

How do i open a chm file through a java program in MAC OS X . I tried using Desktop.getDesktop.open() but it gives me error

Failed to open,edit or print BGDesktop.chm.Error Code -10814

Comment: Do you have a .chm reader?

Comment: It worked in windows without any readers.Anyway Which chm reader should i install?

Comment: No, windows has `hh.exe` to read them.

Comment: So if i install http://chmox.sourceforge.net/ and use the same code,will it work?

Answer (score 0):

By "chm file", I assume you mean a file with "help" content, that is, application documentation for users, and that it is in [Compiled HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Compiled_HTML_Help) format, with a `.chm` filename extension.

Your question presumes that it is convenient, or maybe only that it is possible, to open a Compiled HTML file with Java. Many things are possible if you have the right software, but I haven't found any evidence that such a Java component exists, in my brief search. Microsoft has an [HTML Help Java Applet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/htmlhelp/about-the-html-help-java-applet), but that seems just to help display a Table of Contents, not to parse the Compiled HTML content.

I just had success using the application [Chmox](http://chmox.sourceforge.net/) to read some Compiled HTML content on Mac OS X 10.11. The Wikipedia article linked to above has references to a couple dozen other pieces of software which can read Compiled HTML content in various ways.